# How to replace onclick function call with my function call?

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML code:

```
<td align="center" class="shuttleControl"> 
  <img src="/i/mydb/icons/shuttle_reload.png" onclick="g_Shuttlep_v61.reset();" alt="Reset"  title="Reset"/> 
  <img src="/i/mydb/icons/shuttle_last.png" onclick="g_Shuttlep_v61.move_all();" alt="Move All" title="Move All"/> 
  <img src="/i/mydb/icons/shuttle_right.png" onclick="g_Shuttlep_v61.move();" alt="Move" title="Move" /> 
  <img src="/i/mydb/icons/shuttle_left.png" onclick="g_Shuttlep_v61.remove();" alt="Remove" title="Remove" /> 
  <img src="/i/mydb/icons/shuttle_first.png" onclick="g_Shuttlep_v61.remove_all();" alt="Remove All" title="Remove All" />
```

Based on the above code, using jQuery, how can I replace all the above onclick calls to instead use my JavaScript function `get_Count()`.

So the result I am after is:

```
<td align="center" class="shuttleControl"> 
  <img src="/i/mydb/icons/shuttle_reload.png" onclick="get_Count();" alt="Reset"  title="Reset"/> 
  <img src="/i/mydb/icons/shuttle_last.png" onclick=" get_Count();" alt="Move All" title="Move All"/> 
  <img src="/i/mydb/icons/shuttle_right.png" onclick=" get_Count();" alt="Move" title="Move" /> 
  <img src="/i/mydb/icons/shuttle_left.png" onclick=" get_Count();" alt="Remove" title="Remove" /> 
  <img src="/i/mydb/icons/shuttle_first.png" onclick=" get_Count();" alt="Remove All" title="Remove All" /> 
</td>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd say something like:

```
$('img').unbind('click').click(get_Count);
```

EDIT:

Well, I tried that, and it doesn't work. What does work is `.attr('onclick', '')`. So, do this:

```
$('.shuttleControl img').attr('onclick', '').click(get_Count);
```

Comment: @Spiny, I have other img tags throughout my code so how can I pin point to ensure that I am only referencing the shuttleControl class?

Comment: `.unbind()` is for jQuery handlers.

Comment: @tonsils I edited my post, this should work for you. @patrick Yeah, I just found out about that :)

Comment: @Spiny - I think this has worked - still testing it. Just another query, how would I target just one line only, say the shuttle_last.png line and only change the onclick call for this line alone? Thanks.

Comment: @tonsils Well, since the `img`s don't have an `id`, you'd have to use one of the other selectors (http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/), for example: `$('.shuttleControl img[src="/i/mydb/icons/shuttle_last.png"]')` (or: `$('.shuttleControl img[src$="shuttle_last.png"]')`)

Comment: @Spiny Norman - all worked a treat. Individual selectors worked as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not needing those functions in `g_Shuttlep_v61` at all, you could just overwrite them.

```
g_Shuttlep_v61.reset = 
g_Shuttlep_v61.move_all = 
g_Shuttlep_v61.move = 
g_Shuttlep_v61.remove = 
g_Shuttlep_v61.remove_all = get_Count;
```

Then  there's no need to mess with the inline attributes.

Comment: thanks. where exactly in the code would I set these calls to now use my get_Count call?

Comment: @tonsils: I assume `g_Shuttlep_v61` is a global variable, so just place it in the same scope as your `get_Count` function.